# Classification of covering spaces via Hatcher

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

At the bottom of page $64$ of Hatcher it says:

> The preceding paragraph implies that $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

We've already shown that the map $p|_{U_{[\gamma]}}:U_{[\gamma]} \rightarrow U$ is a homeomorphism, where we've defined
$$U_{[\gamma]} = \{[\gamma\cdot \eta]\mid \eta \text{ is a path in }U \text{ with }\eta(0)=\gamma(1)\}$$

Why is $p: \widetilde{X} \rightarrow X$ continuous?

Comment: I assume the $U_{[\gamma]}$ cover $\widetilde{X}$? Then since each $U_{[\gamma]}\to U$ is continuous, you can glue the maps to a continuous map on $\widetilde{X}$, provided they agree on intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining $p$ gluing together many homeomorphisms along a basis of open sets; this in general leads to a continuous map.

This is the general result.

**Gluing Lemma.** Let $Y$ be a topological space and let $\mathfrak{U}:=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of a topological space $X$. Suppose $\{f_i:U_i\longrightarrow Y\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of continuous functions with the following property: for every $i,j\in I$ such that $U_i\cap U_j\neq \varnothing$ we have 
$$f_i|_{U_i\cap U_j}\equiv f_j |_{U_i\cap U_j}$$
Then there exists an unique continuous map $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ such that $f|_{U_i}\equiv f_i$ for each $i\in I$.